# Recursive method that prints all of the digits in a number that or greater than the first digit and lower than the last digit

Tags: java, recursion

**The problem:**

I'm trying to write a recursive method that prints all of the digits in a number that or greater than the first digit and lower than the last digit.
I accomplished to write a recursive method that prints all of the digits that or lower then the last digit. I can't figure out how to check if the digit is grater then the first digit.

**Examples:**

For print(325648) it will print 5, 6, 4.

For print(237) it will print 3.

For print(925648) it will not print any digit.

**This is my code:**

```
public static void print(int n) {
     print(n,n%10);
}
private static void print(int n,int lastDigit) {
    if(n==0)
        return;
    if(n%10<lastDigit)
        System.out.println(n%10);
    print(n/10,lastDigit);
}
```

**The requirement of this method:**

- Not allowed to use loops(or methods with loops).
- Allowed to use only one recursive transition.
- The length of the number is not known.
- The method can change the number, but at the end of the operation the number should be same as at beginning.

**Please note:**
This is not a homework assignment! I'm writing this method as a practice to a exam that i am talking tomorrow.

Comment: you can use the formula - dig = Math.floor(Math.log10(n)) + 1 to find out no. of digits. Then obtain the first digit by dividing it by dig-1.

Comment: I think this function uses loops.

Comment: Please give one or two example for better understanding

Comment: No. It is a logarithmic function. It can be considered same as to calculate no. of digits using recursion.

Comment: I can run recursion only once on the number.

Comment: you mentioned 3 example, I think second example result is wrong

Comment: @PramodYadav My mistake, I Changed  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here is to recurse by dividing by 10 until the number is reduced to its first digit. On the return through all recursions you have the first digit as a return value and compare quite easily.

```
private static void print( int n ){
    print( n/10, n%10 );
}

private static int print( int n, int ld ){
    if( n < 10 ) return n;
    int digit = n % 10;
    int first = print( n/10, ld );
    if( digit < ld && digit > first )
        System.out.println( digit );
    return first;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I will change it.

Comment: @ laune You have a extra } at the end.

Comment: @sara Thanks. Copy-paste... Fixed.

Comment: Nice solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int firstDigit(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(n != 0 && n / 10 == 0) {
        return n;
    }

    return firstDigit(n/10);
}

public static void print(int n) {
     print(n, firstDigit(n), n%10);
}

private static void print(int n, int firstDigit, int lastDigit) {
    if(n == 0)
        return;
    if(n % 10 < lastDigit && n % 10 > firstDigit)
        System.out.println(n%10);

    print(n/10, firstDigit, lastDigit);
}
```

Comment: Great solution but I can run recursion only once on the number.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the first digit as a parameter.

```
public static int firstDigit(int n) {
    return (int) (n / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(n))));
}

public static void print(int n) {
     print(n, firstDigit(n), n%10);
}

private static void print(int n, int firstDigit, int lastDigit) {
    if(n == 0)
        return;
    if(n % 10 < lastDigit && n % 10 > firstDigit)
        System.out.println(n%10);

    print(n/10, lastDigit);
}
```

EDIT: You can calculate the first digit through recursion too:

```
public static int firstDigit(int n) {
    if (n / 10 == 0) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return firstDigit(n / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think  Math.floor(Math.log10(n) function uses loops.

Comment: Math.floor doesn't ([See here](https://gist.github.com/TheDroide/c650fcc5b0532546ce36a72a4bd541a7)) and Math.log10 is native.

Comment: I cannot say it is not but now you can use recursion to find the first digit or no. of digits and then divide it by dig-1.

Comment: @BB-8 But the StrictMath class contains Math.log10 method and I cannot understand what is given there

Comment: @BrijRajKishore Math.floor(Math.log10(n)) basically calculates the length of the number n.

Comment: @BB-8 does Math.log10(n) uses loops?

Comment: @BB-8 I know. But does this uses loops?

Comment: BTW @sara. I have posted the answer in all by recursion. Please review it

Comment: @BrijRajKishore This is a very good answer but I can use recursion only once. For the first solution I'm not sure if Math.log10(n) uses loops.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, almost your code

```
public static void print(int n) {
         int first = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n).substring(0, 1));
     print(n, first, n%10);
}
private static void print(int n, int first, int lastDigit) {
    if(n==0)
        return;

    if(n%10<lastDigit && n%10 > first)
        System.out.println(n%10);
    print(n/10, first, lastDigit);
}
```

Comment: does Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n).substring(0, 1)) contain any loops?

Comment: Yes. You are going from index i to j for substring

Comment: Here is the example, https://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/

Comment: Nice solution but I can't use loops as the requirement of this method.

Comment: you can check the above link, and no where is mentioned, that substring uses any loop
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
 //check boundary
 return  new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}

Comment: @PramodYadav Great! What about Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n)?

Comment: This link 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html gives details of Integer.toString funcion and 
you can also replace Integer.toString(n) by n + ""
it also works as same, and here is every thing in front of us

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to represent the number to be checked as string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int n = 325648;
    print(n);
}

private static void print(int n) {

    String intAsString = String.valueOf(n);
    int numberLength = intAsString.length();
    if( numberLength < 3) {
        System.out.println("Can't do with ints shorted than 3 digits");
    }

    int firstDigit = Integer.valueOf(intAsString.substring(0,1));
    int lastDigit = Integer.valueOf(intAsString.substring(numberLength-1,numberLength));
    print(intAsString, 0, firstDigit, lastDigit  );
}

private static void print(String intAsString,int index, int firstDigit, int lastDigit) {

    int digit = Integer.valueOf(intAsString.substring(index,index+1));

    if((digit > firstDigit) && (digit < lastDigit)) {
        System.out.print(digit);
    }

    if((index +1) < intAsString.length()) {
        print(intAsString,++index, firstDigit, lastDigit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!! but isn't this too much of a job for accomplishing such a task?

Comment: There are certainly some shorter solutions posted here. It is an alternative, not necessarily the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with string and array compare, I using string because I want code to be bit flexible.

```
public class Data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        print(3245);
    }

    static void print(int n){
        String s = n+"";
        String[] s1 = s.split("");

        printF(Integer.valueOf(s1[0]),Integer.valueOf(s1[s1.length-1]),s1,0);
    }

    static void printF(int lst,int end, String[] ar,int index){

        if(Integer.valueOf(ar[index])>lst && Integer.valueOf(ar[index])<end){
            System.out.println(ar[index]);
        }

        if(index < ar.length-1){
            index = index+1;
            Data.printF(lst,end, ar,index);
        }

    }
}
```

Following the test output of above written code:

```
Input: 3245
output: 4

Input:1234567
output:23456

Input:58697
output:8
```

Comment: Do all functions or with out using loops(s.split, Integer.valueOf, )?

Comment: Split will involve in execution just once per input, rest of the time operation will be on recursive function. And when we go to the recursion then we using are Integer.valueOf for comparison only not any physical or variable assignment.